# How to output CPP files from ProC in Solaris?

Tags: c++, solaris, proc

I tried the following command in Solaris os

```
/ora10gclnt/product/10.2.0/client/bin/proc code=cpp cpp_suffix=cpp database.pc
```

I'm getting the following error

```
#include <stdio.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 2, column 10 in file database.pc
#include <stdlib.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 3, column 10 in file database.pc
#include <string.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the SYS_INCLUDE option to specify the paths that proc should search for header files.

Answer (score 0):

INCLUDE='path' option also works for me